# How to install correctly Vuetify in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have been strugling for a few hours trying to install Vuetify in my laravel project but I cannot make it work correctly, the Vuetify components are working well but Icons and breakpoints are not, I tried everything and now Im kinda tired of this, I hope someone can help me...

Following the vuetify documentation I wrote this in my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import router from './router'

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify.js' // path to vuetify export

Vue.use(Vuex);

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

and separately, a vuetify.js file

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
  },
})
```

and added the vuetify-loader to my webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

    mix.webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
        ]
    }).sourceMaps();

    mix.disableSuccessNotifications();
```

First of all, having this configuration the project wont even run, I get this error: `"Error: Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename fonts/vendor/@mdi/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?a32fa1f27abbfa96ff2f79e1ade723d5"`

So I removed the `import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css"` from the vuetify.js file, no errors but the icons are not visible.

I took the code from the documentation of Toolbar and pasted in my project and this is how it looks

[image]

This is the code for that empty toolbar

```html
<template>
  <v-card
    color="grey lighten-4" flat height="200px" tile>
    <v-toolbar dense>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>

      <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>

      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

If I change `iconfont` from 'mdi' to 'mdiSvg' from the `vuetify.js` file I do get one icon but the others still missing

[image]

According to the documentation, this toolbar should look something like this:[image]

but that's not it yet, I cannot even use vuetify breakpoints like `$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp` I get an undefined error in console

Answer (score 6):

Using Vuetify with Laravel differs a little bit from the the documentation. and depends on Vuetify version and here how to install it for the last two versions

**Vutify v1.5.x**

```
// /resources/js/app.js file

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'; // vuetify style css

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

Vue.use(Vuetify);  // to access $vuetify inside your Vue components
```

A little bit different in **Vuetify v2.0.x**

```
// /resources/js/app.js file

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'; // vuetify style css

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';


const app = new Vue({
   vuetify: new Vuetify(),  // to access $vuetify inside your Vue components
});
```

You can also if you like add `vuetify.min.css` inside `app.scss` file inside resources/sass folder along with material icons as follows:

```
// /resources/sass/app.scss

// Fonts
@import '~@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css';

// Vuetify
@import '~vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I've got a problem when importing the material icons, it says "Error: Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename fonts/vendor/@mdi/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?a32fa1f27abbfa96ff2f79e1ade723d5"

Comment: Probably you imported the library in another file maybe your app.js, keep sure it's imported only once either the /resources/js/app.js file or the /resources/sass/app.scss file.

Answer (score 0):

go to the vuetifyjs website treeshaking method it is the best way!
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/

like the bellow!

```
import Vuetify, {
        VApp,
        VAppBar,
        VAppBarNavIcon,
        VAppBarTitle,
        VMain,
        VNavigationDrawer,
        VFadeTransition,
        VContainer,
        VCol,
        VRow,
        VSpacer,
        VLayout,
        VFlex,
        VContent,
        VDivider,
        VProgressCircular,
        VAvatar,
        VChip,
        VMenu
} from 'vuetify/lib'
import fa from 'vuetify/lib/locale/fa'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    components: {
        VApp,
        VAppBar,
        VAppBarNavIcon,
        VAppBarTitle,
        VMain,
        VNavigationDrawer,
        VFadeTransition,
        VContainer,
        VCol,
        VRow,
        VSpacer,
        VLayout,
        VFlex,
        VContent,
        VDivider,
        VProgressCircular,
        VAvatar,
        VChip,
        VMenu
    },
});

new Vue({
    el: '#yourappid',
    router: router,
    render: h => h(App),
    vuetify: new Vuetify({
        rtl: true,
        lang: {
            locales: { fa },
            current: 'fa',
        },
    }),
    data() {
        return {
            breadcrumbs: [],
            sidebarBg: "deep-purple"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help